# reinstall node.js on a debian machine, over a pre-version

Tags: node.js, github, debian

I'm new to Node ( less every day )
I've got many problems, running express3,request and socket.io :
-  Double log on app.post
- "Can't set headers after they are sent" in the http middleware

When the first problem was corrected ( here on stackoverflow ), then the second one happens ...

Samples taken from natives site show me the same errors.

So, i made a node -v
The version is v0.9.3-pre, installed from Git ( current is 0.8.12 )

I believe this is my main problem, so how can i be sure of the version i am going to reinstall ?
Can this be done by Git ?

On : debian  squeeze

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just download the latest tarball from nodejs.org and go through the usual configure/make/make install sequence, assuming you want to use a stable version of node (which, if you're somewhat new to node, is what you really want to do; development versions (i.e. odd first number in the version) are only intended for people who know node through and through to the point where they can find subtle bugs in it).

I'm using Squeeze on a couple of my machines, and it always works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm going to reinstall my nodejs, this would be better than correct the error i found in the middleware http ( res.end). I would like to understand why i have an alpha/pre version. Is GIT taking the latest dev instead of the latest stable ? Must i consider safier to always use conf/make/inst ?